# How to create a new column from an existing column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([-0.167085, 0.009688, -0.034906, -2.393235, 1.006652], 
                   index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
                   columns=['Feature Importances'])
```

Output:

[image: df - create new col]

Without having to use any loops, what is the best way to create a new column (say called `Difference from 0`) where the values in this new `Difference from 0` column are the distances from 0 for each of the `Feature Importances` values. For eg. for `a`, `Difference from 0` value would be 0 - (-0.167085) = 0.167085, for `e`, `Difference from 0` value would be 1.006652 - 0 = 1.006652, etc.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign a column that operates as the absolute value on the feature importance column:

```
df["Difference from 0"] = df["Feature Importances"].abs()
```

Comment: Many thanks @anon01. If the differences that I want to calculate are not from 0 (say for eg. from 0.5), how would I do this without using loops?

Comment: similar fashion: `df["new col"] = (df["Feature Importances"] - 0.5).abs()`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to find the difference from zero and also get the absolute value.

This should give you the results.

```
df['Diff']  = df['Feature Importances'].abs() - 0

   Feature Importances      Diff
a            -0.167085  0.167085
b             0.009688  0.009688
c            -0.034906  0.034906
d            -2.393235  2.393235
e             1.006652  1.006652
```